# Nginx caching when serving static content

Tags: linux, caching, nginx

I'm serving a directory statically with Nginx, using the following site config, and works well:

```
server {
  listen                 80;
  server_name            spa.me.com;
  access_log             /var/log/nginx/spa-access.log;
  error_log              /var/log/nginx/spa-error.log;
  location / {
     autoindex           on;
     root                /home/ubuntu/spa/dist/;
  }
}
```

Now I want to add **caching** feature to this server. So I've read some posts and:

- Declare a `proxy_cache_path`.
- Use it from my server.
- Add a `X-Cached` header to tell the client the cache status.

So now my config is as follows:

```
proxy_cache_path         /var/cache/nginx/spa levels=1:2 keys_zone=spa:10m inactive=15m;

server {
  listen                 80;
  server_name            spa.mediasmart.mobi;
  access_log             /var/log/nginx/spa-access.log;
  error_log              /var/log/nginx/spa-error.log;
  location / {
     proxy_cache         spa;
     add_header          X-Cached $upstream_cache_status;
     autoindex           on;
     root                /home/ubuntu/spa/dist/;
  }
}
```

For some reason, the `X-Cache` header is never sent, so I'm not able to know (using `curl`, for instance) if a resource is recovered from the cache or not. Furthermore, the cache directory is empty, so it seems no caching feature has been really enabled.

I've also tried to add the `$upstream_cache_status` to my logs file, creating a custom format and using it:

```
...
log_format spa_log_format '$remote_addr - $upstream_cache_status [$time_local] "$request" $status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"';
...
server {
    ...
    access_log /var/log/nginx/spa-access.log spa_log_format;
    ...
}
```

But `$upstream_cache_status` never has a value. Always an empty string is printed on its place in the log.

What I'm doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Why you want to cache static files?

Comment: To serve them from memory instead from disk, @AlexeyTen

Comment: JFYI, `*_cache` directives store cache on disk(!). Also linux kernel already caches files in memory. So, actually, there is no need to use cache for static files. Consider to use `sendfile on` if you haven't already.

Comment: Also `proxy_cache` is only used for proxied request (i.e. thus that are proceeded by `proxy_pass`) and there is no caching directives for static files (for reasons, I wrote before)

Comment: *add_header* doesn't work in one case only, if response code is 4xx or 5xx.